# Constructor setting values based on interfaces which extend the class

Tags: typescript

I have the following example interface/class

```
export interface MyErrorI {
    something: boolean;
}

export class MyError extends Error implements MyErrorI {
    public something = false;

    constructor(message: string, key: keyof MyErrorI ) {
        super(message);

        this[key] = true; // this is the code that I want to reuse
    }
}
```

The concept is that the constructor sets the value of its properties based on its key param.

Now I want to extend it with another class:

```
interface MyNewErrorI extends MyErrorI {
    somethingElse: boolean;
}

export class MyNewError extends MyError implements MyNewErrorI {
    public somethingElse = false;

    constructor(message: string, key: keyof MyNewErrorI) {
        super(message, key);
    }
}
```

Now, the key param can have a property of the interface which extends `MyErrorI`. I don't want to copy/paste the code from the parent class' constructor to the child class' constructor, due to its complexity in my actual problem.

However, the code above can't work because the constructor of `MyError` expects a key of `MyErrorI`. However, the key `somethingElse` is a valid property of `MyNewError`.

So, the question is: **Is it possible that the parent class' constructor accesses the `key` param, each time based on its child class that calls `super`?**

I tried to do something like this, but it didn't work either:

```
export class MyError<T extends PaymentErrorI> extends Error implements MyErrorI {
    public something = false;

    constructor(message: string, key: keyof T) {
        super(message);

        this[key] = true;
    }
}
```

The actual constructor is the following:

```
constructor(message: string, key: keyof MyErrorI | Array<keyof MyErrorI>, data?: any) {
        super(message);

        if (key instanceof Array) {
            key.forEach((v) => {
                this[v] = true;
            });
        } else {
            this[key] = true;
        }

        this.payload = data;
}
```

So calling it using `super(message, key, data)` saves more lines of code, and makes it more maintainable.

Alternatively, could I use a function which has the same functionality?
Something like

```
const setKeys = <T>(err: T, key: keyof T | Array<keyof T>)
```

which would provide the functionality needed. Like this, for `err[key] = true` I get `Type 'true' is not assignable to type 'T[keyof T]'`

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't see an obvious solution, but it hardly seems worth worrying about reusing a single line of code.  Can you give a more realistic example of your scenario?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have updated the question to include a more realistic constructor and a potential alternative

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A function separate from the constructor is probably the way to go, since the constructor can't override the expected `this` type or use the special `this` type to refer to the type of the subclass being constructed, and adding a type parameter just for the sake of the key-setting would be very clunky.  The problem with your function signature is that you haven't ensured that the keys of `T` being passed in have boolean values, so assigning `true` to them might not be valid.  The function definition should be something like this:

```
const setKeys = <K extends keyof any>(err: {[P in K]: boolean}, key: K | Array<K>) => {
    if (key instanceof Array) {
        key.forEach((v) => {
            err[v] = true;
        });
    } else {
        err[key] = true;
    }
};
```

Or you could make `setKeys` a method of `MyError`, since a method (unlike a constructor) can override the expected `this` type:

```
export class MyError extends Error implements MyErrorI {
    // ...
    setKeys<K extends keyof any>(this: { [P in K]: boolean }, key: K | Array<K>) { 
        if (key instanceof Array) {
            key.forEach((v) => {
                this[v] = true;
            });
        } else {
            this[key] = true;
        }
    }
}
```